# Calculating CMOS threshold voltage

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cmos, vlsi, fet

I found this solution in a textbook, and I do not understand how they calculated Vth2 (typo written as 'Vth' at the bottom).

More specifically, where does the 2Vm come from?

I understand that Ids1 = Ids2, but I don't understand how that gets us closer to solving Vth2.

[image]

Comment: Their intuition #2. What does that say to you? To me is says these are IC MOSFETs and not discretes, to start. But what else does it say?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the expression resulting from equating the two drain currents must contain an \$2V_M\$ term. Let us replay the textbook solution with a more detailed discussion:
$$
I_{DS1} = K(V_M-0.3)^2 \tag{1}
$$
$$
I_{DS2} = K\left(0.9-V_M-0.8(\sqrt{0.7+V_M}-\sqrt{0.7})\right)^2 \tag{2}
$$
When equating these two currents, you have a biquadratic equation w.r.t. \$\sqrt{0.7+V_M}\$. The textbook ingeniously solves it first taking square roots of \$I_{DS1}\$ and \$I_{DS2}\$. In doing this, you have two options: equate these square roots either with the same signs on each side or with opposite signs. The textbook selects the same signs (the list item **For '+'**), and, with the help of the two plots below, you can easily make sure for yourself that the other option does not give the solution. First, you plot two currents \$I_{DS1}\$ and \$I_{DS2}\$, similar to the textbook plot.

[image: IDS(VM)]

Then, you plot the square roots of these currents with the same sign before the radix and add the graph for \$-\sqrt{I_{DS1}}\$ with the opposite sign. You see that when the signs are opposite, the graphs have no point of intersection, that is, this convention of the SQRT operation sign gives no solution.

[image: SQRT(IDS(VM))]

But when the signs of square roots \$\sqrt{I_{DS1}}\$ and \$\sqrt{I_{DS2}}\$ are identical, the signs of terms linear in \$V_M\$ in the eq. 1 (\$(V_M-0.3)\$) and eq. 2 (\$(0.9-V_M)\$) are opposite, so the \$V_M\$ term is doubled, whence you see your `2Vm` in the equation where the linear-in-V_M terms are grouped together at one side of the equation.
$$
V_M-0.3 = 0.9-V_M-0.8(\sqrt{0.7+V_M}-\sqrt{0.7}) \\
1.2 - 2V_M - 0.8(\sqrt{0.7+V_M}-\sqrt{0.7}) = 0
$$
Notice also that while \$\sqrt{I_{DS1}}\$ is linear, \$\sqrt{I_{DS2}}\$ is not, although only slightly, due to the contribution of \$0.8(\sqrt{0.7+V_M}-\sqrt{0.7})\$. You can see it in the graph of \$\sqrt{I_{DS2}}\$ derivative, where I intentionally increased the vertical scale.

[image: Diff(SQRT(IDS2))]

As regards the math of my answer, I am admitting that the use of wording "the square root plus/minus sign" is rather careless. A rigorous narrative would use the concepts of the principal square root, the function continuity, etc.

Still more important is to emphasize the role of transistor operating modes in finding a meaningful solution for practical circuit design. You should have noticed the dotted-line segments of curves in the plots. The quadratic law \$I_{DS1} = K(V_M-0.3)^2\$ and an analogous expression for \$I_{DS2}\$ that includes a back-gate contribution, are only valid for MOSFET in saturation. Outside the ranges of \$V_{GS}\$, \$V_{BS}\$ and \$V_{DS}\$ where the transistors are in saturation (I used solid graph lines to indicate these ranges), the transistors operate in ohmic/cutoff modes. Outside saturation ranges the graphs of electrical characteristics are quite unlike parabola segments of the plot of your textbook example.

Summing up, to validate the textbook solution, we should extent the "Intuition" list with the "Constraints" item: Find the solution with both transistors operating in the saturation mode. A useful additional exercise would be to find out if there can exist a solution with a transistor operating in ohmic region.